Korean input with fcitx inputs ideographic space (U+3000)
I'm using fcitx to type Hangul(Korean), but the space bar inputs U+3000 (ideographic space) instead of the normal U+0020. Is there a way to change this?
Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon
Cinnamon 6.0.4
Linux kernel 5.15.0-107-generic
fcitx 5.1.9
